# Accessing Interface in Type Definition File That is Not Exported (Cache Interface in @types/cache-manager)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The [Type Definition file for @types/cache-manager](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/cache-manager/index.d.ts) has the following definition:

```
interface Cache {
    del(key: string): Promise<any>;   
    // 11 other Method Signitures (removed for brevity)
}
```

And also:

```
declare namespace cacheManager {
    function caching(IConfig: StoreConfig): Cache;
    function multiCaching(Caches: Cache[]): Cache;
}

export = cacheManager;
```

I would like to use the `Cache` interface in my code - but can't access it (because it is not exported). My questions are this:

- Is there any good reason the author would not have exported the Cache interface?
- It there any way I can force-export this interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question: I would say no, but that's only my opinion.

Second question: I'm not aware of any way to access a definition that isn't exported.  However, since `Cache` is the return type of exported functions, you can extract it from there, for example:

```
import * as CacheManager from "cache-manager";
type Cache = ReturnType<typeof CacheManager.caching>;
```

Your other option would be to fork the `@types/cache-manager` package into your project using a tool such as [Braid](https://cristibalan.github.io/braid/) (disclosure: I am a Braid contributor), register it as a relative-path dependency in your `package.json`, and then make whatever changes you want.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I added the file cache.interface.ts to my project with the code you supplied above, with the minor addition of adding 'export' before the type declaration.  Now I can import the Cache type from anywhere in my project by referencing this.

Comment: @arhnee, could you post how you referenced cache manager methods(set, del, get etc) after importing the interface?