# TS - Using interface from third party typings

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

Basically I'm using `@types/flickity` to add the definitions for Flickity, but when I try to use the `FlickityOptions` in my own scripts I get an error saying `Cannot find name 'FlickityOptions'`.

I've tried adding `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json` and manually adding the files via `files` but I still get the error, also tried using `/// <reference`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FlickityOptions` is not exported from `@types/flickity`, since the declaration file [sets](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/35f3259b131f366b1d9ea7c9c9a3bf58faa674e0/types/flickity/index.d.ts#L9) `export = Flickity` and `FlickityOptions` is outside the exported namespace.  Consider [filing an issue against DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues) to have `FlickityOptions` exported.  As a workaround, you can extract the `FlickityOptions` type from the `Flickity` constructor:

```
import Flickity = require("flickity");
type FlickityOptions =
    typeof Flickity extends {new(selector: string | Element, options?: infer FO): Flickity} ? FO : never;
```

(Compare to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52172837).)

Comment: I tried the first and I get `Module '"/node_modules/@types/flickity/index"' has no exported member 'FlickityOptions'.`

When I try `Flickity.FlickityOptions` I get `Namespace 'Flickity' has no exported member 'FlickityOptions'.`.

Could this be an issue with the `d.ts` file?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't read the `d.ts` file carefully enough and neglected to test the proposed solution.  See the updated answer.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Could you explain how it works?

Comment: This is using [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) to match the type of the `Flickity` constructor against a pattern and extract the type of `FlickityOptions` that backdoor way.